# Deleting objects within a for loop from a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am working with a `UITableView` and for each of the objects in the array that is the datasource for the `UITableView`, I am deleting them if they meet a certain `if` statement. My problem is that it only deletes every-other object from the array.

Code:

```
UIImage *isCkDone = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UITableViewCellCheckmarkDone"];
int c = (tasks.count);
for (int i=0;i<c;++i) {
    NSIndexPath *tmpPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell * cell = [taskManager cellForRowAtIndexPath:tmpPath];
    if (cell.imageView.image == isCkDone) {
        [tasks removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [taskManager deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tmpPath]
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must run your loop backwards, i.e.

```
for (int i=c-1;i>=0;--i)
```

If you are running it the other way round, removing an object at index position `i` moves the objects in the array that are behind `i` one position forward. In the end you will even run over the bounds of your array.

Comment: You can run the loop forward if you appropriately decrement `i` when an object is removed.  But it's simpler to just run the loop backwards, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to keep your loop running forwards, you could either:

decrement `i` when your condition is met and you `removeObjectAtIndex`

```
    if (cell.imageView.image == isCkDone) {
        ...
        --i ;
        ...
    }
```

or increment `i` **only** when your condition is not met:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<c ; ) {
    ...
    if (cell.imageView.image == isCkDone) {
        ...
    } else {
    ++i ;
    }
```